# Is it possible to create an array from an array in Pascal?

Tags: arrays, pascal

i have a string array called Files, and a boolean function IsGood(Files[i]) in a for loop. How can i create an array of GoodFiles using IF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding you correctly, if you really must have an array you would first have to iterate over your Files array, calling IsGood on each one, and count how many good ones you have, allocate the array, then loop again, this time storing the good ones into the array.

There's another data structure, TStringList, however, that you can conveniently use for something like this:

```
GoodList := TStringList.Create;
for i := 0 to length(Files) - 1 do
  if IsGood(Files[i]) then
    GoodList.Add(Files[i]);
```